# Python Requests and SSLContext

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests, sslcontext

I'm trying to figure out how to specify an SSLContext with Request.

I have two functions which in theory should do the same, however the one with Requests doesn't work.

```
def func_OK(token):
    ctx = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH,cafile='myCA.crt.pem')
    ctx.load_cert_chain(certfile='myprivate.pem')
    url = 'https://my_url.com'
    hdr = {"Content-Type": "application/json","Authorization":"Bearer "+token}
    data = '{"filterList":[{}]}'
    bdata = data.encode('utf-8')
    req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=hdr)
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req, data=bdata, context=ctx)
    content = resp.read()
    data = json.loads(content.decode('utf-8'))
```

```
def func_NOK(token):
    import requests
    url = 'https://my_url.com'
    hdr = {"Content-Type": "application/json","Authorization":"Bearer "+token}
    data = '{"filterList":[{}]}'
    bdata = data.encode('utf-8')
    resp = requests.post(url,headers=hdr, data={"filterList":[{}]})
```

The only the difference between the two functions are the sslContext.
In the func_NOK, I try :

1. `resp = requests.post(url,headers=hdr, data={"filterList":[{}]}, verify=False)` - it doesn't work
2. `resp = requests.post(url,headers=hdr, data={"filterList":[{}]}, cert=('myCA.crt.pem','myprivate.pem'))` - it doesn't work
3. `resp = requests.post(url,headers=hdr, data={"filterList":[{}]}, verify="concat_file.crt")` with "concat_file.crt" file a concatenation of 'myCA.crt.pem' and 'myprivate.pem'

In any cases I have an SSL error.
For example, on my last example the error msg is :

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1131)
```

I'm just trying to use an SSLContext with Requests.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a problem description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it using :

```py
requests.post(url,headers=hdr,json={"filterList":[{}]}, cert='myprivate.pem')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> ctx = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH,cafile='myCA.crt.pem')
> ctx.load_cert_chain(certfile='myprivate.pem')
> ```

`load_cert_chain` loads the cert and private key for use as client certificate - which would be the `cert` argument with `requests`. `cafile` describes the CA it should use to verify the server certificate - which would be the `verify` argument for requests. Combined this would result in:

```
requests.post(..., cert='myprivate.pem', verify='myCA.crt.pem')
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. Error msg : (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1131)')))

Answer (score 0):

I find where my cacert.pem : /home/<soome_path>/pyEnv/myEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/certifi/cacert.pem

I concatenated the files :
myCA.crt.pem >> cacert.pem
myprivate.pem>> cacert.pem

then I specified the path using verify :
requests.post(...,verify='/home/<soome_path>/pyEnv/myEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/certifi/cacert.pem')

And I don't have the ssl error anymore.
However I retrieve an html msg instead of a json.
Maybe an issue on the parameters that I send to the endpoint.

Comment: myprivate.pem was not given as CA in your original func_OK, so it should not be necessary here either. As for needing cacert.pem - it would be really interesting to know more about the server certificate and how it relates to myCA.crt.pem and the publicly trusted CA in cacert.pem.